Ней самой, нею самою или как-то иначе?
Я пишу техническое руководство. В руководстве должно быть сказано, что между заголовком таблицы и таблицей должна быть пустая строка. То есть, должно быть не вот так:
Таблица 1. Сравнение кислого с жёлтым
|-----------------|----------------|
| Кислое          | Жёлтое         |
|-----------------|----------------|
| ...             | ...            |
| ...             | ...            |
|-----------------|----------------|

а вот так:
Таблица 1. Сравнение кислого с жёлтым

|-----------------|----------------|
| Кислое          | Жёлтое         |
|-----------------|----------------|
| ...             | ...            |
| ...             | ...            |
|-----------------|----------------|

Проблема в том, что я запутался в окончаниях.

Между заголовком таблицы и ней самой должна быть пустая строка.

Ней самой, нею самою, ней самою, нею самой? как правильно? Памагити.

Между таблицей и ее заголовком должна быть пустая строка.

Как правильно пишется слово..."Образовка": Правильный вариант написания слова – «помогите». Это производная форма глагола неопределенной формы «помочь», который стоит в повелительном наклонении. Для проверки его написания нужно правильно задать вопрос – «что сделайте?» – «помогите».

Таблица - она не "сама", сам-сама - это человек, субъект, таблица не субъектна. Так же можно повторить слово, это не такая ужасная ошибка и вряд ли ошибка в таком тексте: между заголовком таблицы и таблицей... Вообще, старайтесь не перегружать технический текст лишними местоимениями, лучше повторить термин несколько раз, так, может быть, литературно не очень красиво, зато, НАМНОГО ПОНЯТНЕЕ о чём речь. Ну и лучше слева-направо и сверху-вниз назвать, а не наоборот.
